# notfication won't show up after form submission

Tags: javascript, notifications

i wrote a simple html page in order to test JavaScript notification API
but for some reason when i want to submit the form to trigger the notification, it wont appear
and the browser keeps asking me permission to allow notification, can someone tell me why the notification doesn't appear?

the code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>testing notification</title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" name="meForm" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="para"><br>
    <input type="text" name="para2"><br>
    <select name="location" id="selLocation">
        <option value="Sunnyvale, CA">Sunnyvales</option>
        <option value="Los Angeles, CA">Los-Angeles</option>
        <option value="Mountain View, CA">Mountain Views</option>
        <option value="">China</option>
        <option>Australia</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="sub">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    const form=document.querySelector("#myform");
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission)=>{
        console.log('the permission is ' , permission)
    });
    form.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
        //event.preventDefault()
        let not=new Notification("hey",{
            body:"you submitted the form successfully"});
        setTimeout(()=>{
            not.close()},5000)
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mozilla Docs on Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

This feature is only available in secure contexts, so you have to test it on a domain with **`https`** enabled

But your code is just fine and should work as expected

Comment: So what i understood from that the notification won't appear if i mess with it offline?

Comment: No it won't.. it doesn't work on localhost and if you're online, it will only work in a secure (https) environment